# Unable to display Xml SiteMap on CKEditor

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

Xml.cshtml

```
@Html.TextArea("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue.ToString())
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)', {
    allowedContent: true
});
</script>
```

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [UIHint("Xml")]
    public string Xml { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model Project1.ViewModels.MyViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Xml)
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
     var sitemap = new XDocument(
     new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
     new XElement(ns + "urlset",
        new XElement(ns + "url",
        new XElement(ns + "loc", "example.com"),
        new XElement(ns + "lastmod", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now)),
        new XElement(ns + "changefreq", "Weekly"),
        new XElement(ns + "priority", "0.5")
     )));
     var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
     viewModel.Id = 5;
     viewModel.Xml = sitemap.ToString();    
     return View(viewModel);
}
```

Inside the controller, site map was created and the viewmodel, which holds the `Xml`, sent to the View. In the View, `EditorFor` was converted to `CKEditor` successfully. But the problem is that it removes the Xml tags and displays plain text. If I display the source, `Xml` can be seen properly.
I just installed the `CodeSnippet` plugin and add `config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet';` in the `config.js` but didn't make any difference.
How can I display the sitemap as Xml in the CKEditor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor is the wrong tool to edit a XML document.

If you search a little you'll find that other people have tried that but it's just against the purpose of this editor and you would have to do too many custom changes.

As a general rule, don't try to use a HTML editor to edit XML. Search for a tool designed with XML in mind or use a plain textarea